# Git commit to a sub-directory inside a repository by Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I am using Android Studio Version 2.2 with this plugin "jetbrains-bitbucket-connector_IC-139.224"
I followed this [link](http://www.goprogramming.space/connecting-android-studio-project-with-bitbucket/) to connect my android studio to the bitbucket(or git).

Now, What I want to do is push the code to bitbucket direct from android studio but the location (to which I have to push the code) is a sub directory of the 
repository. i.e.

```
myProject/AndroidCode/
```

where myProject is the root repository and AndroidCode is the subdirectory where
I want to push my code. Any help with this? or suggestion ?